# Pandas groupby with tagging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

sorry I someone already asked it, I can't find solution for my problem.
For example I have dataframe like this:

```
A     B     C   
A-1   B-1   C-1  
A-2   B-2   C-2  
A-2   B-2   C-3  
A-3   B-4   C-4
```

and I want group it by **A** and **B**
so I will have something like this:

```
A     B   
A-1   B-1  #group 1
A-2   B-2  #group 2
A-3   B-4  #group 3
```

But I want to have something like

```
A     B     C    Group_id
A-1   B-1   C-1     1
A-2   B-2   C-2     2
A-2   B-2   C-3     2
A-3   B-4   C-4     3
```

How I can achieve such a result?
Thank you all for helping

Comment: `df['Group_id'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).ngroup() + 1`

Comment: Quang Hoang, but what if I also want to know the size of each group? Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby(['A','B'])['A'].size()`.